# ERROR 3014 (HY000): Table storage engine 'NDBCLUSTER' found required create option missing

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I am trying to create a disk table

```
CREATE TABLE table1_disk 
(col0 INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
col1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (col0)) 
ENGINE=ndbcluster DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
```

Error:
Table storage engine 'NDBCLUSTER' found required create option missing.

I have specified ENGINE type. If I remove STORAGE type the table is created.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1_disk` (
  `col0` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `table1_disk`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`col0`);

ALTER TABLE `table1_disk`
MODIFY `col0` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

Comment: i want ENGINE=ndbcluster not InnoDB.

Comment: @saloman when you answer question explain what is the error and then explain how you your going to solve it without giving answer quickly